# IllegalArgumentException: illegal value no JPA ao recuperar valor de JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, jpa

Estou testando um evento em uma `JTable` do tipo `tableMouseClicked(evt)`, só que estou tendo alguns erros ao retornar os valores nas respectivas JTextField e em uma JSpinner que configurei. Abaixo o Stack Trace referente a saída dada quando eu clico em uma linha para passar a quantidade do tipo `Integer` dentro de uma JSpinner:

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal value
>     at javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel.setValue(SpinnerNumberModel.java:443)
>     at javax.swing.JSpinner.setValue(JSpinner.java:354)
>     at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.tableMouseClicked(ViewPedidos.java:410)
>     at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.access$100(ViewPedidos.java:22)
>     at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos$2.mouseClicked(ViewPedidos.java:210)
>     at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

Está acontecendo esse erro também porém esse é quando alguma coluna da tabela está com valor nulo

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.tableMouseClicked(ViewPedidos.java:382)
>     at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.access$100(ViewPedidos.java:22)
>     at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos$2.mouseClicked(ViewPedidos.java:210)
>     at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

E aqui a implementação o qual estou tentando rodar, ele só está pegando os campos de ID, Data Cadastro, Nome do Produto e Número de Controle e recupera somente estes valores, enquanto os JTextFields Valor Unitário e Código Cliente não consigo recuperar mesmo eles estando inseridos no banco:

```
    private void tableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        int index = table.getSelectedRow();
        PedidoModel pm = (PedidoModel) table.getModel();

        String id = pm.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();
        String dataCadastro = pm.getValueAt(index, 1).toString();
        String nomeProduto = pm.getValueAt(index, 2).toString();
        String numControle = pm.getValueAt(index, 3).toString();
        String quantidade = pm.getValueAt(index, 4).toString();
        String valorUnitario = pm.getValueAt(index, 6).toString();
        String codCliente = pm.getValueAt(index, 7).toString();

        if(pm.getValueAt(index, 0) == null ){
            tfPedido.setText("");
        } else 
        if(pm.getValueAt(index, 1) == null){
            tfDataCad.setText("");
        } else
        if(pm.getValueAt(index, 2) == null){
            tfNomeProduto.setText("");
        } else
        if(pm.getValueAt(index, 3) == null){
            tfNumControle.setText("");
        } else 
        if(pm.getValueAt(index, 4) == null){
            spQuantidade.setValue(0);
        } else 
        if(pm.getValueAt(index, 6) == null){
            tfValor.setText("");
        } else 
        if(pm.getValueAt(index, 7) == null){
            tfCodCliente.setText("");
        } else {   
        tfPedido.setText(id);
        tfDataCad.setText(dataCadastro);
        tfNomeProduto.setText(nomeProduto);
        tfNumControle.setText(numControle);
        spQuantidade.setValue(quantidade);
        tfValor.setText(valorUnitario);
        tfCodCliente.setText(codCliente);
        }
    }
```

E Abaixo o BD:

```
+----+---------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------------+------------+
| id | dataCadastro        | nomeProduto                       | numControle | quantidade | valorTotal | valorUnitario | codCliente |
+----+---------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------------+------------+
|  1 | 2017-04-05 00:00:00 | Lavadora 5Kg Brastemp             |       14221 |          3 |          0 |        942.44 |       NULL |
|  2 | 2017-04-05 00:00:00 | Computador Positivo Intel Core I5 |       41141 |          1 |          0 |       2044.44 |       NULL |
|  4 | 2017-04-05 00:00:00 | Produto X                         |      434342 |          7 |          0 |        444.55 |    3443432 |
|  6 | 2017-04-05 00:00:00 | Mesa Tampo de Granito Bartira     |     1333131 |          6 |          0 |       4444.44 |      44333 |
|  7 | 2017-04-05 00:00:00 | Produto X                         |      434342 |          7 |          0 |        444.55 |    3443432 |
|  8 | 2017-04-05 00:00:00 | Produto X                         |      434342 |          7 |          0 |        444.55 |    3443432 |
| 14 | 2017-04-06 00:00:00 | Produto A                         |     3244333 |          4 |          0 |        555.55 |   34334242 |
| 15 | 2017-04-06 00:00:00 | Produto C                         |      434343 |          2 |          0 |        444.44 |    4434334 |
+----+---------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------+------------+------------+---------------+------------+
```

Abaixo Segue o modelo PedidoModel:

```
package com.exemplo.table;

import com.exemplo.conexao.ConnectionFactory;
import com.exemplo.controller.PedidoDAO;
import com.exemplo.exception.DAOException;
import com.exemplo.model.Pedido;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Vickz
 */
public class PedidoModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private PedidoDAO pedidos;
    private List<Pedido> listpedidos = new ArrayList<>();


    public PedidoModel(PedidoDAO pedidos) throws DAOException {
        this.pedidos = pedidos;
    }

    public void atualizarModel() throws DAOException {
        listpedidos = pedidos.listar();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return "ID";
            case 1:
                return "Data de Cadastro";
            case 2:
                return "Nome do Produto";
            case 3:
                return "Num Controle";
            case 4:
                return "Quantidade";
            case 5:
                return "Valor Unitário";
            case 6:
                return "Cód Cliente";
            default:
                return "[no]";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return listpedidos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int line, int column) {
        Pedido pedido = listpedidos.get(line);
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return pedido.getId();
            case 1:
                return pedido.getDataCadastro();
            case 2:
                return pedido.getNomeProduto();
            case 3:
                return pedido.getNumControle();
            case 4:
                return pedido.getQuantidade();
            case 5:
                return pedido.getValorUnitario();
            case 6:
                return pedido.getCodCliente();
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
```

Tentei inserir cada campo fazendo uma condição caso a coluna do banco seja nula dai a `JTextField` receber campo de texto vazio ou a `JSpinner` setar zero e mesmo assim os erros persistem. Como corrigir este erro?

Comment: Onde exatamente estão as linhas 410 e 382  da classe `ViewPedidos.java`?

Comment: Linha 382 = String valorUnitario = pm.getValueAt(index, 6).toString();
Linha 410 = spQuantidade.setValue(quantidade);

Comment: spquantidade é um jspinner?

Comment: Isso mesmo! dai estou tentando recuperar o valor da coluna quantidade na tabela e inserir esse valor na JSpinner

Comment: Você está passando `quantidade` como String sendo que seu Spinner espera um `Integer`. Faça o parse antes de fazer setvalue.

Comment: Quanto ao outro problema dos campos que não são recuperáveis, precisa ver o seu TableModel.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!! Consegui recuperar agora o valor do campo int da coluna na JSpinner e funcionou!! O TableModel mandei ele agora aqui em cima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há dois erros no código.

Como já mencionado nos comentários, o JSpinner espera um tipo `Integer` e você está passando String. Faça o parse para inteiro de `quantidade` antes de chamar a linha `spQuantidade.setValue(quantidade);`.

O outro erro provavelmente se dá a forma que você está recuperando valores da sua tabela. Observe no seu TableModel que, apesar de ter 7 colunas, ele é ordenado da coluna 0 a coluna 6, e além de pular a coluna 5, você está tentando resgatar um índice de uma coluna 7 que nem existe.

Altere:

```
String id = pm.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();
String dataCadastro = pm.getValueAt(index, 1).toString();
String nomeProduto = pm.getValueAt(index, 2).toString();
String numControle = pm.getValueAt(index, 3).toString();
String quantidade = pm.getValueAt(index, 4).toString();
String valorUnitario = pm.getValueAt(index, 6).toString();
String codCliente = pm.getValueAt(index, 7).toString();
```

para:

```
String id = pm.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();
String dataCadastro = pm.getValueAt(index, 1).toString();
String nomeProduto = pm.getValueAt(index, 2).toString();
String numControle = pm.getValueAt(index, 3).toString();
String quantidade = pm.getValueAt(index, 4).toString();
String valorUnitario = pm.getValueAt(index, 5).toString();
String codCliente = pm.getValueAt(index, 6).toString();
```

Comment: Consegui finalmente, eu fiz essa mudança que o sr colocou ai e no model acabei deixando o atributo valortotal sem nenhuma marcação apenas para poder somar os valores unitários e refiz a classe de entidade e de modelo!